# Join with parent and child IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Imagine that you have a table like this:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| parent_id   | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Let's call this table `locations`

This represents a city or a state.

For example if `name` field is `Los Angeles`, its parent_id would represent a row with a `name` field`California`.

Now imagine that you have another table like this:

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(450)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state           | varchar(135)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Let's call this table `cities`.

Each row represents a city, and the `id` field matches the `id`in the `locations`table.

In this table the `state` field is always empty, so I would like to update it with the `name` field from the `locations` table.

I've tried this query in order to get the `state` value, but it doesn't seem to work (it takes a long time and nothing happens):

```
SELECT name FROM locations WHERE id IN 
(SELECT parent_gid FROM locations INNER JOIN cities  
ON locations.id = cities.id);
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't the information from your second table "cities" completely redundant to the first table? Why do you need it at all?

Comment: You are quite right. Unfortunately it's not in my power to change the Database schema. Anyways this is an abstraction example that once solved would allow me to resolve a larger problem.

Comment: how are the tables related again? what do you want to do, update or select only?

Comment: The two tables are matched through the `id` field. That is, for a certain city its `id` in the `locations` table is the same as the `cities`table and corresponds to the same city name. I want to do the update, but knowing the `SELECT`query would allow me to build the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: try my answer below, willing to update for changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if only only want `SELECT` statement, use `JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, b.name As State
FROM    cities a
        INNER JOIN locations b
            ON a.id = b.id
```

but if you want to update the table,

```
UPDATE  cities a
        INNER JOIN locations b
            On a.ID = b.ID
SET     a.State = b.name
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, c.name As State
FROM    cities a
        INNER JOIN locations b
            ON a.id = b.id
        LEFT JOIN locations c
            On b.parent_ID = c.id
```

Comment: The problem with that `SELECT` query is that it would only retrieve the city name, instead of the state name. That is, `a.name`and `b.name` would hold the same value. In order to retrieve the state name it's necessary to use the `parent_id`field, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: how can you relate `parent_id` on the other table?

Comment: I don't think you can relate it directly, but knowing a city `id` you can retrieve the `parent_id`, and with that `parent_id` the state `name`. I think it's possible to do but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: The updated query works fine with a little tweaking, I will post the corrections I made shortly in case you want to correct it.

Comment: @rfc1484 you can just update my answer and I will accept it `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: I don't know how to save and link it on sql fiddle - but here's the code:

```
create table loca (
   locaid int,
   locaname varchar(25),
   locaparent varchar(25));

create table cityb (
  citybid int,
  citybname varchar(25),
  citybstate varchar(25));

insert into loca (locaid, locaname, locaparent)
  values (1, 'name1', 'parent1');
insert into loca (locaid, locaname, locaparent)
  values (2, 'name2', 'parent2');
insert into loca (locaid, locaname, locaparent)
  values (3, 'name3', 'parent3');
insert into cityb (citybid, citybname, citybstate)
  values (1, 'city1', '');
insert into cityb (citybid, citybname, citybstate)
  values (2, 'city2', '');
insert into cityb (citybid, citybname, citybstate)
  values (3, 'city3', '');

update loca, cityb
    set citybstate = locaparent
      where locaid = citybid;
```

Comment: Unfortunately `locaparent` it's an `id` and I want the state name located in the field `locaname`. However it was a very clear abstraction example, so +1